# How to upload to YouTube without authorization

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I need to check the uploaded videos on a YouTube Channel and then upload missing videos via a CRON JOB.

I first thing I tried was the REST API and the server response with the endpoint was moved.

The problem I ran into with the PHP Google API Client is that it requires the user to authorize the token.

I now tried using the Python Code, but it also requires a authorize session. Also when creating the OAuth 2.0 client ID we are suppose to use OTHER. And there is no OTHER.

[Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python)

Any Ideas? This has been really frustrating as there does not seem to be a lot of examples other than the ones Google provides. I also could not find a rest equivalent. I do not care if the solution is python or Rest or PHP client. I just need a user less CRON job doing the work.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention

Answer (score 4):

What you need to consider is that there are two types of data public data and private data.

Public data is not owned by any user.  Videos on YouTube for example for the most part are publicly available and do not require authorization to access.  On the other had private data is data that is owned by a user.

In order to access public data you just need an api key to identify your application,  however in order to access private user data you need the permission of the user who owns the account in question.

In order to upload to a users account (yes even your own) you need to be authenticated there for you will need to use Oauth2 yes even if you are using a cron job you still need to be authenticated there is no way around this.  There for you will need to create Oauth2 credentials.

What i recommend you do is. Authorize your code once your your local machine store the refresh token and use the refresh token to request a new access token when ever your cron job needs access.  I recomend you give that a try and if you have any issues create a new question include your code and a description of the problem you are having.

This is your only option with the YouTube API.